# C# Tooltip not appearing on "Show"

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

To fullfill a requirement I have to show a tooltip manually for 30 seconds. According to msdn I just have to use the "Show" method.

```
toolTip.Show(QuestionHelpText, btnHelp, 30000);
```

But I only get the standard tooltip behavior, meaning that the message appears half a second after my click (only because the mouse pointer is still over the button). I tried some variations like

```
toolTip.Show(QuestionHelpText, btnHelp);
```

but still, nothing happens.

Does anybody have an idea why that is?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know a simple workaround

Put a lable (let's name it **labelHelp**) with empty text near your button

The following code should work

```
    private void btnHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip.Show(QuestionHelpText, labelHelp, 3000);
    }
```

Comment: it will work for any control. Rob said correct that toolTip.Show is blocking method. so when it is used inside an event handler (i.e. inside btnHelp_Click) of the same control, it will not work as expected. the trick is to call toolTip.Show for a different control. The other workaround solution could be to have a timer and start toolTip.Show asyncroneosuly (for example in btnHelp_Click you start the timer for 0.1 sec, and then call toolTip.Show in a timer event). Using 2nd control looks like an easiest workaround for me.

Comment: I used it in a different handler of another control, and it still doesn't show up

Comment: Ok. the reason it didn't work for me was that I used it in `form_load` event. So I changed it to `form_shown` and now I don't even need a label control to help me with that. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Where is "toolTip" declared?

MSDN doesn't indicate (on the [ToolTip.Show Method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8k201a3(VS.85).aspx)) that the Show method is a blocking call, so if you're declaring toolTip in a method and then pretty much straight afterwards exiting the method then toolTip will have fallen out of scope, causing it to not render or disappear.

Comment: The tooltip is used on the usercontrol, so declared within the InitializeComponent

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set initialDelay property of tool tip