# Why won't my C++/CLI tooltip appear?

Tags: windows, forms, c++-cli, tooltip

I have some validation code which should display the max / min of a control when a bad value is entered.

In my constructor I do this:

```
m_wndToolTip = gcnew ToolTip(this->components);
m_wndToolTip->AutoPopDelay = 5000;
m_wndToolTip->InitialDelay = 10;
m_wndToolTip->ReshowDelay = 250;
m_wndToolTip->ShowAlways = true;// Force the ToolTip text to be displayed whether or not the form is active.
```

This is my validation reflection code:

```
void MyGUI::IndicateValidationResult(Windows::Forms::Control^ control, bool isValid, String^ invalidReason)
{
    // If the validation failed, make the background red. If not, turn it white.
    if( isValid )
    {
        control->BackColor = Drawing::Color::White;
        m_wndToolTip->Hide(control);
    }
    else
    {
        control->BackColor = Drawing::Color::LightCoral;
        m_wndToolTip->Show(invalidReason, control);
    }
}
```

...which is called from varous `ValueChanged` methods in my text boxes. I've tried using show and also a combination of `SetToolTip` and `active = true` and nothing seems to work.

I've seen [another question asking about tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086153/c-tooltip-not-appearing-on-show) and have tried setting a nearby label in the call to show but that doesn't fix it either. The tooltip is a member variable in my `System::Windows::Forms::Form` derived form to stop it going out of scope.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked fine when I tried it, there's no obvious mistake that I can see.  I called it like this, using a Validating event of a text box:

```
bool ok;

System::Void textBox1_Validating(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::CancelEventArgs^  e) {
  e->Cancel = !ok;
  IndicateValidationResult(textBox1, ok, "invalid");
  ok = !ok;
}
```

Beware that ToolTip can be cranky.  The native Windows component has a "feature" that prevents a tooltip from showing again when it timed out before.  The ErrorProvider component is a better mouse trap to get this done.